# LDO Regulator Power Good Output Pin Question

Tags: voltage-regulator, ldo

[MCP1755](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/268/25160A-238586.pdf) has Power Good Output (PWRGD) output pin which is open drain. In page 15 of data-sheet it says

> The PWRGD pin may be pulled up to VIN or VOUT. Pulling up to VOUT conserves power when the device is in Shutdown (SHDN = 0V) mode.

1) How should I connect this pin. Should I leave it as not connected or pull it up to Vout pin with 10K. (I will not monitor the operation of converter I want only proper 3.3v regulation).

2) What is the exact purpose of this pin. Should we connect it to an ADC to see the operating condition if we want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect it through 10k to Vout. The pin is just a logic output, you can see from the second block diagram on page 3 of your datasheet that it's the output of a comparator. It would not be connected to an ADC. The pin could be used to drive a LED, the datasheet shows that it has sufficient current capability: 1mA is enough for an indicator.

Answer (score 2):

Connect PWRGD through 10k to Vout.

On page 5,6,7 the manufacturer tells you how to connect it.
You can find it in AC/DC Characteristics.

Example:

> Electrical Specifications: Unless otherwise specified, all limits are
>   established for VIN = VR + 1V, Note 1, ILOAD = 1 mA, COUT = 1 µF
>   (X7R), CIN = 1 µF (X7R), TA = +25°C, tr(VIN) = 0.5 V/µs, SHDN = VIN,
>   PWRGD = 10K to VOUT. Boldface type applies for junction temperatures,
>   TJ (Note 7) of -40°C to +125°C.

As for SHDN. As a manufacturer tells you it's used to enable or disable the conversor.

Also if you are going to use this circuit as a simple conversor I would switch to a MCP1755S if you can.

Hope this helps you